# Visual Studio XAML: Differentiate Inherited vs Local Properties (New Version)

Tags: xaml

In earlier versions of Visual Studio, the Properties window showed **colored squares** next to each XAML property

- a white square for local properties
- and a green square for inherited properties.

However, newer versions of Visual Studio no longer use these squares. How can I effectively differentiate between inherited and local properties in this new version?